# Getting an error when using tf.keras.metrics.Mean in functional Keras API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I'm trying to add a Mean metric to a Keras functional model (Tensorflow 2.5), and am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Expected a symbolic Tensor for the metric value, received: tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Here is the code:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [5 + i * 3 for i in x]
a = Input(shape=(1,))
output = Dense(1)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a,outputs=output)
model.add_metric(tf.keras.metrics.Mean()(output))
model.compile(loss='mse')
model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=100)
```

If I remove the following line (from which the exception is thrown):

```
model.add_metric(tf.keras.metrics.Mean()(output))
```

the code works as expected.

I Tried disabling eager execution, but I get the following error instead:

```
ValueError: Using the result of calling a `Metric` object when calling `add_metric` on a Functional Model is not supported. Please pass the Tensor to monitor directly.
```

The above usage was pretty much copied from the [tf.keras.metrics.Mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Mean) documentation (see *Usage with compile() API*)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to bypass the problem by avoiding usage of `model.add_metric` altogether, and passing a `Metric` object to the `compile()` method.
However, when passing an instance of `tf.keras.metrics.Mean` as follows:

```
model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=tf.keras.metrics.Mean())
```

I get the following error from the `compile()` method:

```
TypeError: update_state() got multiple values for argument 'sample_weight'
```

To solve this, I had to extend `tf.keras.metrics.Mean` and change the signature of `update_state` to match the expected signature.
Here is the final (working) code:

```
class FixedMean(tf.keras.metrics.Mean):
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        super().update_state(y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
y = [5 + i * 3 for i in x]
a = Input(shape=(1,))
output = Dense(1)(a)
model = Model(inputs=a,outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse', metrics=FixedMean())
model.fit(x=x, y=y, epochs=100)
```